# Can not click elements in javascript modal using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am trying to use Selenium WebDriver to click the 'OK' button in a modal that appears after submitting a form on a page.

`Driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` fails, and so does switching the window handle. I have also tried `Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement()` but that also fails. The driver is still recognising elements on the page before the button that opens the modal was clicked, so I know it is definitely not switching over, which makes Xpath and CssSelector useless for the meantime.

I have tried switching browsers but that doesn't have an effect.

```
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Confirm?</p>
<div class="alert alert-block">
<p> Are you sure? You can not undo this </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<input type="button" class="btw" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="button" value="OK" id="confirmation-submit" class="btn btw-primary">
</div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a very similar problem to yours with the following code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(okButton_id));
IWebElement okButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id(okButton_id));
okButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Clement's answer solved this for me. Except, I was using python, so what you need to do is invoke:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
```

Or for more seconds if this doesn't work.